# How to remove period (.) from OL numbering?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, xhtml

http://jsbin.com/urice

I want to remove `.`  after number.

`1.` should be `1` only

With All browser compatibility inducing **IE6** and validity.

I need solution without javascript.

**Edit :**

If it's not possible with css only then a simple javascript and jQuery solution would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: @cazlab - yes i need css solution if possible

Comment: Using pure css I don't think it's possible, but I'd be interested to find out.

Comment: Why do you need pure-javascript **and** jQuery? And I edited the question to make it a little less demanding, and more courteous.

Comment: Aside from IE6 compatibility (gosh, weren't those the days? ), this question has a wider range of answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5945161/2652785

Answer (score 3):

There is this, not sure how many browsers support it though.

```
ol {
list-style-type:none;
} 

ol li:before {
content:counter(number) " ";
counter-increment:number;
counter-reset: number;
}
```

Working example [here](http://jsbin.com/urice/5/). I have it working in Chrome.

Comment: Doesn't match the criteria for IE6 compatibility though. Certianly not without js.

Comment: @ricebowl - you can give javascript solution if it's not possible using css only

Comment: Aye, I kinda figured IE wouldn't support it. But at least it's an option for the real browsers, then could just use some JS for IE.

Comment: It's not working in Chrome for me - you're missing `counter-reset: number;` on the list.

Comment: Edited to add `counter-reset: number;`.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, the only way do what you want completely cross browser is to not use the list numbering at all. Just put `list-style:none` on the list and type the numbers manually:

```
<ol>
  <li>1 The first item</li>
  <li>2 The second item</li>
</ol>
```

If you're generating code server-side, then it's a lot easier since you can use an incrementing variable in your loop.

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery to find the < li > and inserting an incrementing number into their .innerHTML is probably the best way to do this using javascript.