# HTML + CSS: Ordered List without the Period?

Tags: html, css, separator, html-lists

I think the answer to this question is no... but does anyone know of a an HTML/CSS way to create an ordered list without a period after the numbers? Or, alternatively, to specify the separator character?

Ideally I don't want to do list-style-image with a different class for each number, but that's all I've been able to think of so far... That seems terribly unsemantic.

IE:

```
Default Style:
1. ______
2. ______
3. ______

Desired Style:
1  ______
2  ______
3  ______

Alternate Style:
1) ______
2) ______
3) ______
```

Comment: Seems that you are screwed up with the periods :) I think the only way is constructing the list by yourself with `<ul>`

Answer (score 87, accepted):

This is perfectly possible to do with just CSS (2.1):

```
ol.custom {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-left: 0;
}

ol.custom > li {
  counter-increment: customlistcounter;
}

ol.custom > li:before {
  content: counter(customlistcounter) " ";
  font-weight: bold;
  float: left;
  width: 3em;
}

ol.custom:first-child {
  counter-reset: customlistcounter;
}
```

Keep in mind that this solution relies on the :before pseudo-selector, so some older browsers -- IE6 and IE7 in particular -- won't render the generated numbers. For those browsers, you'll want to add an extra CSS rule that targets just them to use the normal list-style:

```
ol.custom {
  *list-style-type: decimal; /* targets IE6 and IE7 only */
}
```

Comment: For what it's worth this didn't work until I moved the `counter-increment` to the `li` itself. Don't know why... Otherwise this is great, thanks!

Comment: This worked great for me, checked as far back as IE8, thanks so much!  Never knew about this ability before.

Comment: This only seems to work for `list-style-position: inside`. Any help on getting this to work for `list-style-position: outside`?

Comment: This approach is using pseudo-elements, so any CSS property to affect list-styles -- `list-style-position`, `list-style-type`, etc. -- won't work. You need to style the `::before` pseudo-element.

Comment: To make this work for multiline list items, add the following css. ol.custom>li { display: table-row }  ol.custom>li:before { display: table-cell }

Comment: ol.custom>li:before float:left must be removed also.

Comment: just ignore people using ie6 and 7 - they are used to the internet being broken and will be confused if your site works.

Answer (score 8):

Here is the solution

[Number nested ordered lists in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2729927/number-nested-ordered-lists-in-html)

All you have to to is change a little bit here

```
ol li:before {
                content: counter(level1) " "; /*Instead of ". " */
                counter-increment: level1;
            }
```

^^

Comment: +1, This is the only way with pure CSS, but I don't believe it's well supported (yet) unfortunately. **EDIT:** I stand corrected, according to that link, it works in all current browsers.

Comment: Any ideas how to add a leading zero?

Comment: @yckart This is a years-late response, but in case it somehow helps someone, see https://jsfiddle.net/a3L6e24s/ In the li::before's rule you can set `content: "0" counter(mycounter) " ";` and then set `ol.leading0 li:nth-of-type(9)~li::before {content: counter(mycounter) " ";}` . If one needed to support IE8 one could make the selector `ol.leading0ie8 li + li + li + li + li + li + li + li + li ~ li:before`

Comment: @JacobC. Wow! Thanks alot for answering this 5 years old question and supporting IE8 :-)

Answer (score 7):

This can be achieved using the [`::marker`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3A%3Amarker) CSS pseudo element, which has pretty good browser support.

Note however, that Safari has an [outstanding bug](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=204163) to support the `content` property, so this approach will not work there. In some cases this might be okay since the fallback behavior will just display the extra period.

```css
ol { counter-reset: my-counter-name; }

li { counter-increment: my-counter-name; }

li::marker { content: counter(my-counter-name); }
```

Comment: A brilliant up-to-date answer. (Though I look forward to when `::marker` can understand more CSS properties than the limited subset it comprehends at present.)

Comment: This should probably be added to a class. Adding a counter to the tag itself will increment all the numbers in `<ol>` elements on the page.

Answer (score 5):

You can remove the dots with CSS by specifying an empty suffix for the [counter style](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@counter-style):

```css
@counter-style empty-style {
  system: extends decimal;
  suffix: ' ';
}

ol {
  list-style: empty-style;
}
```

You can further style the numbers with the [`::marker`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::marker) pseudo-element.

Note that this technique [is not supported at all](https://caniuse.com/css-at-counter-style) in Safari (any version) or in legacy Edge. But, fortunately, it just degrades nicely in these browsers, rendering the default dot without issues.

So, it is a good progressive enhancement.

Answer (score 4):

I just found a workaround for cases where you want to simply remove the dot. Not the best solution ever, but it's done with only CSS and works in every browser. The downside is that you need the textnode in the LI to be wrapped into another tag (<span> or something). In my own case, the <ol> was used as a list of links, so I could use my <a> tags !

The CSS I used :

```
ol li a {
    float: right;
    margin: 8px 0px 0px -13px; /* collapses <a> and dots */
    padding-left: 10px; /* gives back some space between digit and text beginning */
    position: relative; z-index: 10; /* make the <a> appear ABOVE the dots */
    background-color: #333333; /* same background color as my ol ; the dots are now invisible ! */
}
```

Comment: Interesting approach, thanks. No problem answering an old thread, sometimes you're adding very useful info.

Comment: This only works if you have a background with a single colour.

Answer (score 4):

The above solutions all have drawbacks for some lists: multiline items, multidigit item numbers, custom background, etc.

It's cleaner to use the built-in `list-item` counter instead of a custom counter:

```
ol.dotless {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-left: 0;
}
ol.dotless > li:before {
  content: counter(list-item) "\A0";
  float: left;
  text-align: right;
  width: 1.5em;
}
```

But this approach does not work with multiline items.

There is a new method that allows you to directly format a counter, but so far, it only works in Firefox:

```
ol.dotless {
  list-style: dotless-item
}
@counter-style dotless-item {
  system: numeric;
  symbols: "0" "1" "2" "3" "4" "5" "6" "7" "8" "9";
  suffix: " ";
}
```

The only method I've come across that works in all cases is a `table` that mimics an `ol`:

```
table.dotlessol {
  margin: 0.25em 1.25em;
  border-spacing: 0;
  counter-reset: dotless;
}
table.dotlessol tr {
  vertical-align: top;
  counter-increment: dotless;
}
table.dotlessol td {
  padding: 0;
}
table.dotlessol td:first-child {
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 0.5em;
}
table.dotlessol td:first-child::before {
  content: counter(dotless);
}
```

Use two `td`s in each row, leave the first `td` empty, and put the item text in the second `td`.

Comment: The `@counter-style` method was what I was looking for, thanks! Also, adding `@counter-style dotless-item { system: extends decimal; suffix: ' '; }` works just the same, removing the dots. Anyway, this technique is not supported in Safari or in legacy Edge, but it just degrades gracefully in these two, displaying the dots.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the numbers later using jQuery:

```
$("ul").each(function() {
   $(this).find("li").each(function(index) {
      $(this)
        .css("list-style-type", "none")
        .prepend("<div class='listnumber'>" + (index + 1) + "</div>");
   })
})
```

Try the sample [here](http://jsfiddle.net/MV72g/).

More info on jQuery [here](http://docs.jquery.com/How_jQuery_Works).

Answer (score 0):

This is the simplest solution without counter-increment and inline tags inside li:

```
ol {list-style-position: inside; overflow: hidden; direction: rtl;}
li {position: relative; left: -15px; text-align: left; letter-spacing: 5px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can first remove the marker and replace it with before element
for better browser support and then use the builtin list-item counter

```
ol {
list-style:none
};
li::before {
content: counter(list-item)
}
```

**expected result**

```
  1 item 
  2 item 
  3 item
```

## Edit

the **<li>** should have `display:list-item;` wish is the default