# How to remove dot "." after number in ordered list items in OL LI?

Tags: html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [HTML + CSS: Ordered List without the Period?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5945161/html-css-ordered-list-without-the-period)

Want to remove dot "." from OL (order list)

```
<ol>
<li>One</li>
<li>Two</li>
</ol>
```

Result

```
 1. One
 2. Two
```

Required Result

```
 1 One  
 2 Two
```

Comment: See the answer [over here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5945305/74757). Note, the technique doesn't work in older IE browsers.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

This will work in IE8+ and other browsers

```
ol { 
    counter-reset: item;
    list-style-type: none;
}
li { display: block; }
li:before { 
    content: counter(item) "  "; 
    counter-increment: item 
}
```

or even:

```
ol li:before {
  content: counter(level1) " "; /*Instead of ". " */
  counter-increment: level1;
}
```

If you want older browsers to be supported as well then you could do this (courtesy neemzy):

```
ol li a {
    float: right;
    margin: 8px 0px 0px -13px; /* collapses <a> and dots */
    padding-left: 10px; /* gives back some space between digit and text beginning */
    position: relative; z-index: 10; /* make the <a> appear ABOVE the dots */
    background-color: #333333; /* same background color as ol ; the dots are now invisible ! */
}
```

Comment: tell more about browser support and accessibility

Comment: @Vladimir Starkov: IE8+, doesn't harm accessibility in any way as it's still an `ol`.

Comment: @VladimirStarkov It's work till IE8 & above

Comment: @BoltClock I know it. but it must be included in answer for future users

Comment: May have problems if the text goes over multiple lines. I would suggest the [following amendments](http://jsfiddle.net/26rW4/1), as per [this stackoverflow answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/486662/1171529).

Comment: Yes this work, also noticed that we do not require to add list-style-type:none; in OL.

Comment: @BoltClock Its work fine in IE8 too

Comment: Downside is that this becomes selectable text so not good for number <pre> with code examples.