# HTML5/CSS - <ol> with letters and parentheses?

Tags: css, html, html-lists

I'd like to know if it's possible to use letters with ")" intead "." in an ordered list. Something like this:

```
a) Some text...
b) Some text...
c) Some text...
```

Until now I'm getting:

```
a.) Some text...
b.) Some text...
c.) Some text...
```

So I need to eliminate the points.

CSS:

```
.theclass ol li{
  margin: 0 0 0 1em;
}

.theclass ol li:before{
  content: ') ';
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -3.4em;
  text-align: right;
  width: 3em;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="theclass">
 <ol type="a">
   <li>Some text...</li> 
   <li>Some text...</li>  
   <liSome text...  </li> 
 </ol>
</div>
```

Comment: Would be great if you refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11946098/how-to-remove-dot-after-number-in-ordered-list-items-in-ol-li

Comment: I asked MarLen to refer it in his answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found this.

*I don't have enough points to commend. 
This is not my solution!*

Found it here: [Ordered list (HTML) lower-alpha with right parentheses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1632005/ordered-list-html-lower-alpha-with-right-parentheses)

Example on [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nKtE6/2/)

```
ol {
counter-reset: list;
margin: 0; }

ol > li {
list-style: none;
position: relative; }

ol > li:before {
counter-increment: list;
content: counter(list, lower-alpha) ") ";
position: absolute;
left: -1.4em; }
```

I think this is what you are looking for..?

Another answer can be found here:
[How to remove dot “.” after number in ordered list items in OL LI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11946098/how-to-remove-dot-after-number-in-ordered-list-items-in-ol-li) answered by Moin Zaman

Comment: Adding counter-reset: list; to ol worked perfectly. Many thaks.

Comment: Could you refer in your answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11946098/how-to-remove-dot-after-number-in-ordered-list-items-in-ol-li also? Thanks.

Comment: Just one thing: the question was answered by Moin Zaman. I think it's better to remove "Update" and say: Another answer can be found here: (the link). Thanks.