# align text on multiline with css

Tags: css

I have a menu, when the window is smaller, I have text on multiple line. I search how to make the text align. But the text go under the first part instead of the beginning of my text/span. I cant use css flex because its not supported on IE9 and IE10.

```
<ul>
  <li class="menu13">
    <span class="number">1</span>
    <span class="dot">.&nbsp;</span>
    <span class="text">menu 1</span>
  </li>
  <li class="menu2">
    <span class="number">2</span>
    <span class="dot">.&nbsp;</span>
    <span class="text">menu 2 is so long that I need to find a way to align multiple line. So I want no padding left on the second line. But I cant use css flex because it not working on IE9. I cant use width (like menu 5).</span>
  </li>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/at24sxmx/

you can see the menu 3 on my fiddle, made with flex (I search an alternative)

Comment: Why don't you use <ol> instead of <ul>. Then you don't need those extra spans too.

Comment: I need the number without the dot on mobile.

Comment: You can use CSS for mobile devices:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11946098/how-to-remove-dot-after-number-in-ordered-list-items-in-ol-li

Comment: I will retry with ol and make the number invisible on desktop version. tanks

Comment: It needed little tweek but it worked with ol . tank you mojtaba. Just needed somebody to call a "You should rethink your thing".

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `.menu4 span` selector and update your HTML:

```
<span class="number">4</span><span class="dot">.&nbsp;</span><span class="text">menu 4 - test with block . Not working, so Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah.</span>
```

Make sure you **delete** new lines characters from HTML, here is a result: https://jsfiddle.net/at24sxmx/5/

Comment: I need menu 2 like menu 3 but without css-flex.

Comment: sorry but I dont see your patch on your fiddle

Comment: witch one should be right? On firefox, there's still only the number 3 that show it right. (you can stop looking, I change to ol instead of ul with number)

Comment: Your previous css is messing around with other items, you don't need ANY css to make it work into single line, just delete white spaces between spans inside that item.