# How to Prepend Ordered List Items with Pound Sign

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to prepend an ordered list with the Pound Sign or the Hash Symbol?

Like this:

```
#1. something
#2. something else
#3. another thing
...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Here's a solution](http://jsfiddle.net/pjmorse/t3LU5/) following the hints suggested by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5945305/306084):

HTML:

```
<ol class="custom">
    <li>First item</li>
    <li>Second item</li>
    <li>Third item</li>
</ol>
```

CSS:

```
ol.custom {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-left: 0;
}

ol.custom > li {
  counter-increment: customlistcounter;
}

ol.custom > li:before {
  content: "#" counter(customlistcounter);
  font-weight: bold;
  float: left;
  width: 3em;
}

ol.custom:first-child {
  counter-reset: customlistcounter;
}
```

The "custom" classname just makes it possible to revert to the original behavior; if you take it out, this will apply to all `ol` tags using this stylesheet. Note the limitations introduced by using the `:before` pseudo-selector: IE6 and IE7 will have trouble with this.

Comment: The only problem I am having now @pjmores is my <ol> tag looks like this `<ol class="custom" reversed>` ... your css is un-doing the reverse ordering of my list. Might you be able to suggest how I can restore the reverse-ordering? Thanks

Comment: I see. This is using [a custom counter](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#counters). The last rule (`counter-reset: customlistcounter`) is setting it to 0 at the first element, and each one is increasing by one (that's the second rule). You can decrement the counter with `counter-increment: customlistcounter -1`. `counter-reset: customlistcounter 10` would start each list counting down from 10... I don't know how you'd dynamically set that value, though.

Comment: That worked perfectly and I figured out how to "dynamically" set the initial counter value via PHP echo. Thanks @pjmorse

Comment: Oh, yeah - you could set the counter in the `ol` element itself, and the code generating that element probably knows how many items go in the list. I didn't think of that - good follow-through.

Answer (score 0):

CSS

```
.hash-counter {
    counter-reset:hash;
    list-style-type: none;
}

.hash-counter > li:before {
    counter-increment:hash;
    content:"#" counter(hash) ". ";
}
```

But it could cause some other problems.