# Change ol from 01. to 01

Tags: css, html-lists

Is it possible to lose the dot when using "list-style-type:decimal-leading-zero;"

I found a solution to lose the dot, but then I can't add the leading zero.

```
ol { 
    counter-reset: item;
    list-style-type: decimal-leading-zero;
}
li { display: block; }
li:before { 
    content: counter(item) "  "; 
    counter-increment: item 
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML + CSS: Ordered List without the Period?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5945161/html-css-ordered-list-without-the-period)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can set the list-style-type for the counter:

```
ol { 
    counter-reset: item;
    list-style-type: none;
}
li { display: block; }
li:before { 
    content: counter(item, decimal-leading-zero) " "; 
    counter-increment: item;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this dude! I've been searching for a few hours on how to do this properly.

Comment: There is a working example here https://codepen.io/maddesigns/pen/JGQejg